# Difference between how to set path to the theme folder

Tags: paths

I crate many wordpress based sites. When i need to include path to the theme folder, i use this code `<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>`. I`m **Theme check** plugin. And they say to me

> bloginfo('template_url') was found in the file services-section.php. Use echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) instead.

What the difference between this to methods? Which is better to use?

Comment: you can look at [`get_bloginfo` in source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L601) and see what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **‘template_url‘ / ‘template_directory‘** – URL of the active theme’s directory. Within child themes, both get_bloginfo(‘template_url’) and get_template() will return the parent theme directory. Consider echoing get_template_directory_uri() instead (for the parent template directory) or get_stylesheet_directory_uri() (for the child template directory).

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/bloginfo/

the function `get_template_directory_uri()` is the better one, if you want to support creating child themes. if you don't care, it shouldn't matter much.

**edit:**

did a simple speed test and found no significant difference:

```
blog_info('template_url')    0.00010 sec 
get_template_directory_uri() 0.00007-0.00010 sec
```

Comment: do they have some speed difference?

Comment: no, added some speed test results :)